# typeset and return status in ksh

Tags: ksh, exit-status, typeset

I'd like to be able to declare a local var as the result of a command AND to be able to capture return status of command.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
typeset -r command_output=$(command)
typeset -r return_status=$?
echo "$return_status" # always 0
```

The problem with the snippet code above is return_status will always be 0, even if command exit with another status code.

Any one to help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `typeset` creates the return status. This code (i.e. both assignments in the same declaration) works for me:

```
typeset -r command_output=$(command) return_status=$?
```

To keep the `return_status` writable (not read-only) you can do:

```
typeset    command_output=$(command) return_status=$?
typeset -r command_output
```

(i.e. declare the read-only variable as the subsequent command).

Comment: You are right Janis, thank you very much !
What if I want return_status not to be a constant (to be reusable ?)

Comment: For your additional question I added the solution to my answer.

Comment: Easy to do, thanks for pointing me this complete solution